# Xmlparser for html to pdf

Tags: java, html, pdf, xml-parsing, itext

This is a small snippet of my code.It works fine but what if I wanted to add a number to each String variable str.
How do I do that?Please help.
Collections.shuffle(arrlist);

```
for(int i=0;i<nb;i++){
    String str = (String) arrlist.get(i);
     //worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader("<br>")); 
     worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(str));   
}
```

Comment: In this case I get str(line break)str(line break) and so on.But I want 1 str (line break) 2 str(line break )

Comment: what number? want to add `i`?

Comment: Yup i or anything else

Comment: Suresh gave you the answer. Is it fine or you need something else?

Comment: It doesnt work.The number doesnt appear on the pdf page.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String str = (String) arrlist.get(i)+String.valueOf(someNumber);
```

If you want to add `i`

```
String str = (String) arrlist.get(i)+String.valueOf(i);
```

**Update**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List arrlist = new ArrayList<>();
        arrlist.add("tester");
        int i = 0;
        String str = (String) arrlist.get(i) + String.valueOf(i);
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

**o/p:**

```
tester0
```

Comment: What ?? adding `String.valueOf(i)`, Not making any difference ?

Comment: So can you please give some example, what you are getting and what you want ?  I added some example.If not  please cross check.The error is some where else.

Comment: I am doing it on JSP page,was trying to send a screenshot.

Comment: Cant post a screenshot coz  of my reputation.

Comment: I think the xml parser must be creating a problem.Still I doubt that..Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes,the error lies some where else. Glad if I helped you something.